# vuejs app with vue router hosted on amplify direct url to file doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, file, vue-router, aws-amplify

I have an issue on which I struggled all day long, I have a VueJS app with vue router that I host on amplify?
everything working great **Except that**

I need to give a direct access to a file (I want to register an Apple merchant ID with stripe)

I tried to create a route in my route/index.js with my file name that redirect to a component that open the merchantid file with an windows.open('myfile').
it works great on local serve and build but not once deployed through amplify built with webpack

```
//router/index.js

import WellKnown from '@/components/AppleVerification.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [

{
  path: '/.well-known/apple-app-site-association',
  component: WellKnown,
 }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

export default router
```

```
// AppleVerification.vue

<template>
    <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'WellKnown',
  props: {
    file: String
  },
  mounted () {
    window.open('file:///.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association')
  }
}
</script>
```

so I went to amplify console and make a redirection with first priority to the URL and target address to the file. but it didn't work also.

[image: Amplify rewrite image]

I went out of ideas on how to give access to a file in my sources with a direct URL.

would appreciate a little help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You issue comes from the acces to the file througth Amplify for several reasons.

Try following:

1. rename your endfile "apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association"
   with an extension like
   apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt
2. remove the dot in your path public/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association to public/well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt

in your amplify console create a priority 1 rule that redirects your
https://mydomain/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association to
/well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt with a 202 rexrite method.

It should work

You even didn't need the component anymore